# CSS not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, web-frontend

Css is not applied when I open my page in Firefox. However it does work in google chrome.Following are the details:

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>    
    <link type="text/css" href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet">   

</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dolorem fierent vim ea. Duo no discere
        voluptatum. Eum eu adhuc appareat, dolores imperdiet sea ea. Pri ut
        cetero consectetuer, ad populo sensibus ius. Nominavi persecuti pro ad,
         bonorum imperdiet moderatius cu cum, tollit tritani numquam ex qui.

           </p>

</div>

   </body>
</html>
```

External CSS: Style.css

```
 #content{
    width:300px;
    height:500px;
    background:#e3e3e3;
    border:1px solid #666;
    margin-top:40px
    }

    #content p{
    padding:20px;
    }
```

Comment: Seems to be running fine in firefox. Here's a pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKvwdb  Any particular thing that isn't working?

Comment: Is it something with the filename? Possibly chrome looks for `style.css` while Firefox is looking for `Style.css`? The CSS is valid so there shouldn't be a problem with that. You'll have to look elsewhere.

Comment: What is the `xml:base` thing? Why don't you have a `<style>` tag before `#content`?

Comment: `</link>` is not valid.  You seem to be enclosing CSS elements in `<link></link>` which is wrong.  Internal CSS like this should be wrapped in a `<style></style>` tag.

Comment: I am attaching my screenshot, in question details

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Invalid html can have random behaviour in different browsers. Fix your link and style tag. You dont need an external link element for internal css. It needs to be enclosed in a style tag.

Comment: @RobertC :That was output of Firebug, not actual html page.

Comment: What do you mean not actual html page?

Comment: Actual mean , the one it was written not from Firebug.

Comment: This is a convoluted and confusing question. How about you provide a link to an actual example or add a code snipet.

Comment: I am sorry about that.I am editing the question now.

Comment: It works like a charm in Firefox: https://jsfiddle.net/cne4c7gk/ Style.css is in the same folder as the html file?

Comment: Have you placed the file in the correct location? Check the console to make sure you're not getting a 404 error for the css file

Comment: Ohh yeah It was in right location.Restarted my machine and it worked !

Comment: You are mixing up doctypes, html5 with xhtml. Remove the xmlns.

Comment: @Liliput How long were you trying to find the problem before writing here?

Comment: I was trying for 1 hour or so since it was working in Chrome , I was not posting here.May be 1 hour 45 minute.

Comment: This is such a trivial thing that i would have to work in firefox withou restarting your machine. You had to fix some error, probably didn't even notice that. Use some web developer tools to prevent 404 and other errors. Stack Overflow can't help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Just add style tags arround your CSS:

```
<style>
#content{
width:300px;
height:500px;
background:#e3e3e3;
border:1px solid #666;
margin-top:40px
}

#content p{
padding:20px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `link` tag should be used to link the HTML page to a separate CSS stylesheet. You **cannot** insert CSS into a `link` tag. To do so, just use the `style` tag :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css" type="text/css" />
<style>
#content{
width:300px;
height:500px;
background:#e3e3e3;
border:1px solid #666;
margin-top:40px
}

#content p{
padding:20px;
}
</style>
<style id="web-developer-edit-css-styles-0" class="web-developer-edit-css-styles" xml:base="/C:/Users/user1.Data/Desktop/CssNoobToNinja/CssNoobToNinja/">
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dolorem fierent vim ea. Duo no discere voluptatum. Eum eu adhuc appareat, dolores imperdiet sea ea. Pri ut cetero consectetuer, ad populo sensibus ius. Nominavi persecuti pro ad, bonorum imperdiet moderatius cu cum, tollit tritani numquam ex qui. </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -4):

If you're going to just use inline css just use the `<style>` tag like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<style>

#content{
  width:300px;
  height:500px;
  background:#e3e3e3;
  border:1px solid #666;
  margin-top:40px
}

#content p{
  padding:20px;
}
</style>
<style id="web-developer-edit-css-styles-0" class="web-developer-edit-css-styles" xml:base="/C:/Users/user1.Data/Desktop/CssNoobToNinja/CssNoobToNinja/">
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dolorem fierent vim ea. Duo no discere voluptatum. Eum eu adhuc appareat, dolores imperdiet sea ea. Pri ut cetero consectetuer, ad populo sensibus ius. Nominavi persecuti pro ad, bonorum imperdiet moderatius cu cum, tollit tritani numquam ex qui. </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** Huge brain fart, put `<script>` instead of `<style>` it is fixed now

Comment: <script>? Are you sure?

Comment: You don't use a `<script>` tag for this. You use a `<style>` tag.

Comment: Why is it in a script tag?

Comment: Yeah had a massive brain fart and wrote script instead of style, my bad.